# Error from nested query with GeoDjango

Tags: django, geodjango, subquery, spatial-query

I'm having trouble constructing nested queries using [`in` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) in GeoDjango. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
inner_qs = Footprint.objects.filter(geom__bboverlaps=bounding_box)
outer_qs = Footprint.objects.filter(pk__in=inner_qs)
outer_qs.count()
# error
```

With the above code, the follow exception occurs:

```
if (len(params) == 1 and params[0] == '' and lookup_type == 'exact'
  File "../python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/adapter.py", line 24, in __eq__
    return (self.ewkb == other.ewkb) and (self.srid == other.srid)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ewkb'
```

(Here is the [complete stack trace](https://gist.github.com/1098188))

It appears that the error occurs whenever the inner query contains a spatial filter. The following nested query works fine though:

```
inner_qs = Footprint.objects.filter(frequency__gt=1)
outer_qs = Footprint.objects.filter(pk__in=inner_qs)
outer_qs.count()
# ok
```

Any idea what causes the problem?

Comment: Get the same error calling Q.exists() on empty geoqueryset... geodjango is great but really strange sometimes. Will post something  if I can find the cause

Comment: Was dancing around it for quite some time. In 5 mins after posting comment realized that stupidly forgot to add GeoManager... )

Comment: How did you fix your error? You mean you forgot to add `objects = models.GeoManager()` in your model class?

Comment: Yes - i was using custom manager inherited from standart manager.